# cygwin, compiling ncmpcpp: error: ‘postfix_increment_proxy’ is not a class template

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile, cygwin

i'm trying to compile ncmpcpp on cygwin. i got it to configure after wrestling with dependencies, but when i try to make this error pops up:

```
In file included from utility/comparators.h:26:0,
                 from utility/comparators.cpp:22:
./mpdpp.h: In constructor ‘MPD::Directory::Directory(const mpd_directory*)’:
./mpdpp.h:134:62: error: ‘mpd_directory_get_last_modified’ was not declared in this scope
   m_last_modified = mpd_directory_get_last_modified(directory);
                                                              ^
In file included from ./menu.h:26:0,
                 from ./format.h:26,
                 from ./settings.h:32,
                 from utility/comparators.h:27,
                 from utility/comparators.cpp:22:
/usr/include/boost/range/detail/any_iterator.hpp: At global scope:
/usr/include/boost/range/detail/any_iterator.hpp:131:15: error: ‘postfix_increment_proxy’ is not a class template
         class postfix_increment_proxy<
               ^
/usr/include/boost/range/detail/any_iterator.hpp:176:15: error: ‘writable_postfix_increment_proxy’ is not a class template
         class writable_postfix_increment_proxy<
               ^
Makefile:603: recipe for target 'comparators.o' failed
make[2]: *** [comparators.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/aritsune/ncmpcpp/src'
Makefile:455: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/aritsune/ncmpcpp'
Makefile:365: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

i'm new to compiling from source and this error seems pretty unique. what could be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have all the prerequisites required. Always address the errors in the order they occur. The first error occurs in `mpdpp.h`, on line 134, `mpd_directory_get_last_modified`. If I Google `mpd_directory_get_last_modified` the first result is a link to documentation for `libmpdclient`. Make sure you have this library and your compiler can find it.

As for the Boost error, if you are using version 1.57, it sounds like this bug:

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10754

which is discussed in this thread:

[Can't compile boost/any_iterator.hpp in boost 1.57](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759817/cant-compile-boost-any-iterator-hpp-in-boost-1-57)